# Adding directory to PATH -- Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, software-installation, django

I realize that there are several similar questions out there and I'm unsure if I'm simply misunderstanding the solutions. I only recently began using Ubuntu, so I'm still familiarizing myself with everything.

I'm trying to set up the Django web-development framework and when I install it via the terminal, I receive this message:

> "WARNING: The script django-admin is installed in '/home/bp102412/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location."

The following is what I've tried so far:

`PATH=$PATH:home/bp102412/.local/bin` in .bash_profile

and

```
if [ -d "new_dir" ] ; then
  PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:new_dir"
fi
EXPORT $PYTHONPATH
```

But, I was also reading that you shouldn't use `EXPORT` on bash_profile.

I've restarted the shell after each change to the file and received the message each time, so I'd appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Note: I found that if I source `~/.bash_profile` that it solves the problem, but I don't want to source it each time I plan to use this package in the terminal, I'd like it to be included in the `PATH` each time the terminal starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution by looking for the answer as to why I had to source it each time. Since I was in a non-login shell, .bash_profile was never sourced by the terminal. Logging in graphically only sources .profile. I added `PATH+=$PATH:home/bp102412/.local/bin` to the bottom of .profile and everything now seems to be running smoothly.